# How to avoid revenge downvotes?

Tags: support, plagiarism, downvote-reason

I really don't know if this is the right place to ask this question, but I really don't know where else to ask this, so here goes -
So I've just started programming, and to dive in deeper, I've created a Stack Overflow account. I try to help as much as I can with my limited knowledge.
Anyways, I came across this particular question today -
[Question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62793303/how-use-input-function-in-pyhon)

Immediately upon seeing the first answer, I knew that it was plagiarised, and hence I pointed out the same by commenting on the answer. However as soon as I commented this, I faced a barrage of downvotes in all of my questions/answers asked till date, bringing down my reputation from 101 to 83.

I really don't like plagiarism, and I feel pointing it out is the best I can do. But on the other hand, I cannot lose my reputation as well due to this Revenge downvote barrage I faced today. I never faced this side of stack overflow community before.

Do I need not to do anything when I see somebody copy-pasting answers? Or is there a something else that needed to be done which I didn't know about?

Any kind of help would be great, as being a newbie, getting reputation is really tough, so I don't want to lose the same. However I don't want to endorse plagiarism as well.

Hence please let me know what do to in future if I come across plagiarised content on Stack Overflow. Also, please let me know if there is any way I can challenge the downvotes?

Comment: The best way to avoid revenge downvotes is to not comment. Instead, raise a flag and explain why you think the content is plagiarised and then let a moderator handle it from there.

Comment: Yes, what @ivarni said. Please raise a moderator flag and let us handle it. We take plagiarism very seriously, and we appreciate all reports of it! Reporting it to a moderator will take the "heat" off of you and hopefully avoid revenge downvotes. Nevertheless, *sometimes* inappropriate downvotes happen, which is why we have a script that automatically detects and reverts them. I've marked this question as a duplicate of the FAQ on that.

Comment: On two posts you even got 3 downvotes in a very short time period, which means that more than one account is involved. Smells like sock puppets.

Comment: @CodyGray we also need a better way to flag plagiarism (probably another type of flag) .. I am afraid that my [plargiarism] flags will simply age away lost in all the custom flags

Comment: @TemaniAfif We could probably use a new custom flag type, yes. I can't remember if that's been proposed before on Meta, or if it's just on my to-do list. However, in the meantime, rest assured that custom moderator flags never age away. So, we'll get to them eventually.

Comment: @CodyGray - If a plagiarism flag is provide.  Please provide a mechanism to provide a url as an indication, so a moderator (or the community), can make an educated decision on the flag.  The lack of formatting in a custom flag makes it difficult to explain the reason something has been plagiarized (copy and paste, improper citation, improper quotation, etc).

Comment: @Sec Yes, that was my intention and imagined design: you'd have a *mandatory* field to fill out with a link of where the plagiarized content was taken from. In the mean time, do note that you can use mini-markdown in your moderator flags (the same thing you'd use in comments). Bold and italics are supported, but not really useful. What is useful is the inline link markdown. And even if you don't use that, just pasting the bare hyperlink is fine; they do turn into links for us to click on in the mod flag dashboard.